# Need help manually installing nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I downloaded the nltk package from https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data (I cannot use nltk.download() due to proxy issues) and put it at C:\nltk_data. When I try 'import nltk' from the python interpreter I get this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named nltk

I do not know how to get the python interpreter to see the folder. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the Python interpreter will check the library path before its running. 
You can use `sys.path` in python interpreter to check the place.
Always by default, python will add the running path to the library path which in linux like "./".

If you want to run the python in another path, In Windows there are two ways to solve this problem.

1. You can add a environment variable

   C:\Users\Administrator>set PYTHONPATH=C:\nltk_data
2. Or you can add it in you python script like:

   sys.path.append("C:\nltk_data")

PS: 
Dobule check the path(\ or /) which is in different types between Windows and Linux.